# rabbitmq - active active solution over wan and lan

Tags: rabbitmq, messagebroker

From the active/active documentation -
     [we have developed active/active high availability for queues](http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)

> This solution still requires a RabbitMQ cluster, which means that it will not cope
>       seamlessly with network partitions within the cluster and, for that reason, is not
>       recommended for use across a WAN (though of course, clients can still connect from
>       as near and as far as needed)

What does it mean "not recommended for use across a WAN".
I cant understand this remark -
If I buy three machines on ec2 will I need to establish a domain controller/dns server?
What does this restriction mean? and why?

Answer (score 2):

Replication is a **time-sensitive application**, this means that timing assumptions have to be done in order to get the distributed state synchronized across the replicas.

The Internet is an **asynchronous network** per definition, the network asynchronously evolves and there's no way to make assumptions on delivery times, neither in case MPLS (Multiprotocol Label Switching) paths are defined: the BGP (Border Gateway Protocol) introduces a lot of unpredictability, paths can be very unpredictable, and this translates in unpredictable latency.

According to above, **unpredictable latency is a killer factor for Active-Active replication** (i.e. mirroring the state synchronously among the replicas to reach a consistent distributed state).

Another problem to be taken into consideration consists in the **Network Partitioning**: in a set of replicas, one or more can be isolated creating "islands of non-consistent replicas": let's assume the replica set *R = { R1, R2, R3, ..., RN }*, for network connectivity reasons (e.g. BGP problems) a subset of replicas like *{R1, R2, R3}* may be isolated from the remaining ones. Network partitioning implies distributed state inconsistencies: the subset of replicas will be consistent, but globally they evolve independently towards a corrupted distributed state.

The [CAP Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) deals with the replication problem over the WAN (Wide Area Network, i.e. the Internet). It states:

> Consistency, Availability and Partitioning cannot be achieved over the WAN or another asynchronous network, 2 out of 3 need to be chosen for large scale distributed systems (e.g. Availability and Network Partitioning for the well known NoSQL databases).

Coming back to the original question: according to above, that statement (from RabbitMQ documentation) tries to sum up in a pragmatic way the problems that I highlighted above (i.e. Active-Active replication cannot be achieved over the WAN). For this reason, if you need to replicate your Broker instances over the WAN, techniques like the [Shoveling](https://www.rabbitmq.com/shovel.html) and [Federation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html) are commonly used in RabbitMQ deploys.

Answer (score 0):

It means if you have 3 EC2 instances in your cluster, they should be in the same data center. Not US East and US West for example*. RabbitMQ uses Erlang's node communication and is pretty chatty. Low latency communication is critical to having a performant cluster.

*Ideally even the same subnet, but that's not always possible.